# Missing Symbols in VS2010 Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, missing-symbols

Using VS2010 with an older Win32 C/C++ Project, 
I'm trying to track down missing symbols in a project recently built.  In the past I've used lib.exe to examine contents of libraries, but that doesn't seem to work anymore.  For example

```
lib /List:libname.lib
```

returns only: 
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved..

So what are the best practices for tracking down missing symbols in VS2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repro, the command line syntax you use is wrong.  Omit the colon:

```
C:\projects\cpptemp3\Debug>lib /list cpptemp3.lib
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Debug\stdafx.obj
Debug\test.obj
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as looking for symbols goes, I use dumpbin /symbol [lib or obj file]